Not able to install flutter app in external device
Actually, I am installing the Flutter app on an external device but am not able to install it.
It shows not able to find class com.appazon.appazon.MainActivity. It only shows that the app is installing but never installs.
Here is the error:

E/AndroidRuntime(29040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.appazon.appazon/com.appazon.appazon.MainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.appazon.appazon.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/~~OM2AzhFMd9XUFVOiiYzuPQ==/com.appazon.appazon-gzQHt98phAih6HHo86Rtng==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~OM2AzhFMd9XUFVOiiYzuPQ==/com.appazon.appazon-gzQHt98phAih6HHo86Rtng==/lib/arm64,
/data/app/~~OM2AzhFMd9XUFVOiiYzuPQ==/com.appazon.appazon-gzQHt98phAih6HHo86Rtng==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
/system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]



I've noticed this,

E/AndroidRuntime(29040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.appazon.appazon/com.appazon.appazon.MainActivity

Please check the MainActivity class by navigating to your project's android/app/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt
In your POV, it should be look like this:
package com.appazon.appazon

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity()

Take note: you don't have to modify that class unless you're using feature in your app that tells that you have to modify it. Always refer to official documentation of Flutter for more info.
Tips: add the ADB Interface for VSCode extension in your VS Code if you haven't installed it yet. It saves your time in connecting your physical devices with your project.
